# How to prevent IIS from killing SignalR connection?

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

My ASP.NET Website  (Hosted in IIS) will connect to SignalR hub once it is started. (I put the connection code in Application_Start).

But I found out that sometimes the website will disconnect automaticaly because of some configuration in IIS recovery?

How do I keep this connection alive between my website server and signalR 
[image]

Comment: IMO you should not strive to solve that problem, you have to assume that your connection WILL go away, and design your solution to work despite of that.

Comment: SignalR client should try reconnecting to the server. Is this not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour is that SignalR reconnects after App pool recycle. SO you must have some custom code that does not survive this?

I solved it like this in my library

```
$.connection.hub.reconnected(this.reconnected.bind(this));

reconnected: function () {
    var temp = this.activeSubscriptions;
    this.activeSubscriptions = [];
    this.queuedSubscriptions = temp;
    this.sendSubscribeQueue(true);
}
```

It saves all subscriptions in client memory and when reconnect happens it will resend the subscriptions to the server

You can roll something similar or maybe my library fits your use case?

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Comment: Please don't rely on client's input :(

Comment: You need to validate it on server offcourse. The way above library does that is, https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki/Implement-constraint-handlers